# How to avoid WebException in a GetResponse() method

Tags: .net, exception, httpwebrequest, .net-2.0

I'm executing the following code:

```
 // get a picture from http://www.mysite.com/logos/logo.png
 WebRequest pictureRequest = WebRequest.Create(themeLogoUri);
 response = pictureRequest.GetResponse();
```

The logo in the webSite could exists or not, and when it doesn't exist, the `GetResponse()` method fails throwing a `WebException (404)`. Until here all it's correct.

When I'm debugging, it's annoying to have always this exception because the debugger always stop in this exception. I know that I can ignore a kind of exceptions in the debugger, but I prefer avoid throwing the exception, so my question is.

How could I check that the request is correct (the image really exists) so if not exist, return and in other case continue with the `GetResponse()`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

create a simple function with the try/catch statements and call it instead

Comment: If you read the answer, I say that I want to check if the webRequest exist, I want to avoid the exception so, this answer is not valid. Please, delete it.

Comment: @DanielPeñalba, why don't you simply create a method (or extension method) that does exactly that: `DoesTargetExist`. It only needs to contain a try/catch, inside the `catch` you return false, at the end of the `try` you return true. To prevent downloading the whole picture, use `WebClient`, `OpenStream` en `Read`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need it just for debugging purposes?
Then indeed, mark to ignore it in the debugger settings.

If not, and if you can change your server behavior, then you probably can program a web-service there which will return you an indication of file existence on the server.

HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() will throw an exception anyway.
Do not use HttpWebRequest class if you do not like this behavior.

Comment: I need something to check if the webrespose exists.

Comment: If you look at the code of HttpWebRequest with Reflector or dotPeek you'll see that exception is thrown intentionally. So probably you would like to re-implement the same code, or use another classes for sending requests.